# Add a file/directory to rkhunter checking

Tags: rkhunter

My question is very simple and I'm very surprised to see that this question haven't be asked before.

How to add a file or a directory to rkhunter checking ? With that I could see my directory appears in the 'rkhunter --propupd' command
I know I can modify the .dat file but if I do that , I'd rather do a script myself to check for md5sum/sha1sum for my specific directory

Hope that someone could help me ! Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Maybe I confused you (of course I did, I wrote *or* instead of *and*...)

Here's a step by step:

```
mkdir /var/local/test
touch /var/local/test/test.bla
```

add config in `rkhunter.conf`:

```
USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="/var/local/test/test.bla"
```

run `rkhunter --propupd`

run `rkhunter --check [--sk]` (if you want to, should return no errors or warnings)

edit the file `/var/local/test/test.bla`

run `rkhunter --check [--sk]`

my output:

```
/bin/dash                                                [ OK ]

/var/local/test/test.bla                                 [ Warning ]
```

You can also use `/var/local/test/*` as wildcard for all files in that directory.

---

It's a command line argument for `--propupd`:

From the man page (emphasis mine)

> --propupd [{**filename** | **directory** | package name},...] One of the checks rkhunter performs is to compare various current file properties
>   of various commands, against those it has previously stored. This
>   command option causes rkhunter to update its data file of stored
>   values with the current values. **If the filename option is used, then
>   it must either be a full pathname, or a plain file name (for example,
>   'awk'). When used, then only the entry in the file properties database
>   for that file will be updated. If the directory option is used, then
>   only those files listed in the database that are in the given
>   directory will be updated.** Similarly, if the package name option is
>   used, then only those files in the database which are part of the
>   specified package will be updated. The package name must be the base
>   part of the name, no version numbers should be included - for example,
>   'coreutils'. Package names will, of course, only be stored in the file
>   properties database if a package manager is being used. If a package
>   name is the same as a file name - for example, 'file' could refer to
>   the 'file' command or to the RPM 'file' package (which contains the
>   'file' command) - the package name will be used. If no specific option
>   is given, then the entire database is updated.
>
> WARNING: It is the users responsibility to ensure that the files on
>   the system are genuine and from a reliable source. rkhunter can only
>   report if a file has changed, but not on what has caused the change.
>   Hence, if a file has changed, and the --propupd command option is
>   used, then rkhunter will assume that the file is genuine.

<s>Or</s> And, of course, change it in `rkhunter.conf`:

```
#
# This option is a space-separated list of commands, directories and file
# pathnames which will be included in the file properties checks.
# This option can be specified more than once.
#
# Whenever this option is changed, 'rkhunter --propupd' must be run.
#
# Simple command names - for example, 'top' - and directory names are
# added to the internal list of directories to be searched for each of
# the command names in the command list. Additionally, full pathnames
# to files, which need not be commands, may be given. Any files or
# directories which are already part of the internal lists will be
# silently ignored from the configuration.
#
# Normal globbing wildcards are allowed, except for simple command names.
# For example, 'top*' cannot be given, but '/usr/bin/top*' is allowed.
#
# Specific files may be excluded by preceding their name with an
# exclamation mark (!). For example, '!/opt/top'. By combining this
# with wildcarding, whole directories can be excluded. For example,
# '/etc/* /etc/*/* !/etc/rc?.d/*'. This will look for files in the first
# two directory levels of '/etc'. However, anything in '/etc/rc0.d',
# '/etc/rc1.d', '/etc/rc2.d' and so on, will be excluded.
#
# NOTE: Only files and directories which have been added by the user,
# and are not part of the internal lists, can be excluded. So, for
# example, it is not possible to exclude the 'ps' command by using
# '!/bin/ps'. These will be silently ignored from the configuration.
#
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="top /usr/local/sbin !/opt/ps*"
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="/etc/rkhunter.conf"
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="/etc/rkhunter.conf.local"
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="/var/lib/rkhunter/db/*"
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="!/var/lib/rkhunter/db/mirrors.dat"
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="!/var/lib/rkhunter/db/rkhunter*"
#USER_FILEPROP_FILES_DIRS="/var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/*"
```

This should add it to the rkhunter db.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! but that doesn't help...Do I have to manually change de database file ? Or can a file be added "dynamicaly"  thanks to a command ?

Comment: @KaAzZ why is it not working? What happens?

Comment: Ok , so let's assume that I want to add the dir "/var/www/html" to rkhunter check

If I understand what you meant I should do :
`rkhunter --propupd /var/www/html`

But it won't work cause the directory isn't in the .dat file...

My question is very simple , how can you add a directory to rkhunter checks ?

Comment: @KaAzZ check my edited answer